# Oracle sql or pl/sql: give flag for each group based on specific column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I want to add flag for each SHOP based on which product contain

select a.product, a.shop
from data a

[I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssohe.png)

[I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r8LBj.png)

I try something like this but it do not work

```
select a.product, a.shop
,case when row_number() over(partition by a.product, a.shop order by a.shop) = 1 
  and a.product = 'a' then 'contains product A'
  and (a.product = 'a' and a.shop = 'b') then 'contains product A & B' end FLAG
from data a
```

Comment: when its shop 1 its product a and 2 then a and b products ? can you specify all the conditions

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option:

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (produkt, shop) as
  2    (select 'a', 'shop_1' from dual union all
  3     select 'a', 'shop_1' from dual union all
  4     select 'a', 'shop_1' from dual union all
  5     select 'a', 'shop_2' from dual union all
  6     select 'b', 'shop_2' from dual
  7    ),
```

Query begins here: first aggregate produkts per each shop ...

```
  8  temp as
  9    (select shop,
 10            listagg(distinct produkt, ' & ') within group (order by null) flag
 11     from test
 12     group by shop
 13    )
```

... to, finally, return desired result set:

```
 14  select a.produkt, a.shop, 'contains product(s) ' || b.flag as flag
 15  from test a join temp b on a.shop = b.shop
 16  order by a.produkt, a.shop;

PRODUKT    SHOP   FLAG
---------- ------ ------------------------------
a          shop_1 contains product(s) a
a          shop_1 contains product(s) a
a          shop_1 contains product(s) a
a          shop_2 contains product(s) a & b
b          shop_2 contains product(s) a & b

SQL>
```